# JAIN SIP setPathName()

Tags: android, jain-sip

I'm trying to develop an android SIP app (SiPapp.example.org) with Jain Sip api, following this example [http://www.telestax.com/jain-sip-stack-for-android](http://www.telestax.com/jain-sip-stack-for-android/) and I am not sure if I have completely understood sipFactory.setPath().
 What should I put between that brackets?
 In the example, it says `sipFactory.setPathName("android.gov.nist");` should I put my packqge name(org.examle)?
I'm stucked with this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use "android.gov.nist". See example here https://github.com/Mobicents/restcomm-android-sdk/blob/master/Examples/JAIN%20SIP/src/org/mobicents/restcomm/android/sdk/impl/SipManager.java#L129